# Microsoft graph - Is there a way to update multiple emails at once?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

According to this https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_update

I have to do individual patch requests to update messages (e.g. marking them as unread or something).

But this becomes a problem when there are too many (mark 10 emails as unread from my custom dashboard powered by microsoft's graph api)

Is there a way to update multiple emails simultaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON batching is now available in the beta endpoint that will let you update multiple messages at once.  Docs are at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching.

We also have batching samples in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) so you can easily try out batching in your browser.

[image: graph explorer batching samples]

Answer (score 1):

Graph doesn't support batching multiple calls yet. You can currently batch if you call the Outlook endpoint directly (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/batch-outlook-rest-requests).